# How to wait for nested Task in Android Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following method:

```
    public static void getRecipe(DocumentReference DR){
        Recipe r = new Recipe();

        /*First Firestore Query! - Get the recipe*/
        DR.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {

                    r.addStuff(...);
                    r.addMoreStuff(...);
                    r.addEvenMoreStuff(...);   
              
                    /*Second Firestore Query(s)! - Get the ingredient(s)*/
                    for(DocumentReference DR_ingredient : ingredients) {
                        Task<DocumentSnapshot> IngredientQuery = DR_ingredient.get();

                        IngredientQuery.addOnCompleteListener(t -> {
                                    if (t.isSuccessful() && t.getResult() != null) {                                      
                                         /*even more stuff*/
                                    }
                        });
                    }


                    //After all tasks are finished, we can finally put the recipe in our Database!
                    Task<Void> t = Tasks.whenAll(IngredientQueries);
                    t.addOnSuccessListener(unused -> {
                        addRecipe(r);
                    });
                 
                }
           });
}
```

The method uses Firestore to get a saved recipe and furthermore load the ingredients for the selected recipe. The ingredients are saved as a reference inside of the recipe and must be loaded again per Firebase.

**My Question now is**: If I call `getRecipe(DocumentReference DR)` from another class, how can I wait until everything is loaded and then continue with my code?

Comment: Tasks are always asynchronous and deliver their results to callbacks.  Your function should containue to use some sort of callback mechanism to deliver the results to any callers.

Comment: How would I do that?